# Fullcalendar: new items double display - date at left always am/pm - parseDate

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar for a while now, if it's finished I will *definitely* put it open source somewhere, because it isn't good that there is not an example implementation somewhere. Anyway, I have three questions before everything is working properly:

I can successfully create a new item, but when I go to another week (in the weekview) and go back, then the item appears twice. One instance is from the database, and the other one from fullcalendar I guess. I do a ".fullCalendar('renderEvent',ev,true);" after successfully storing an item. Can I prevent this problem?

Furthermore, I can't set the left side date format. It's still in am/pm and whatever I try with timeFormat (currently "timeFormat:'H:mm'"), it doesn't listen. I really really can't easily read the am/pm format (just like about half of the world), so it's really quite annoying...

And I was wondering, how do I translate the start and end when creating a new item, into a timestamp? This is the only string that goes over the wire, and I'm parsing it by hand in PHP now. I would love to use .fullCalendar.parseDate() at the clientside, but I didn't succeed. This is probably easy, I know.

Thanks a lot!!!

Niels

Answer (score 0):

for your first question, use renderEvent w/o the true. when refetching happens, it will be wiped away, which is what you want.

2nd question.. timeFormat should work, so can you make a bug report on the issue tracker (with full demo)?

not really sure i understand your 3rd question